# Possible to control vertical source ordering with 960 Grid System?

Tags: css, 960.gs, grid-layout

I've understood it's possible to control the horizontal (columnwise) source ordering with the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs). However, is it possible to do something similar vertically?

If not, does anyone know of any grid system that handles source ordering vertically?

Thanks,
Jens

Comment: Apparently it doesn't seem like it, since noone has answered...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a grid system (css framework) with both horizontal and vertical control?

Few days ago I tried [#grid](http://hashgrid.com/) and I think it does what you are looking for